Flutter app: White screen after restart on Android with Java 17 upgrade
I was using Java 8 with my Flutter app. I recently upgraded to Java 17. After the upgrade, the app installs and runs perfectly on the first launch, showing all screens as expected. However, upon restarting the app, I am stuck on a white screen. API calls seem to be going through in the background, but the UI fails to render.
I've tried cleaning the Flutter project with flutter clean and restarting the device, but the issue persists.
How can I debug this white screen issue that appears after restarting the app following a Java 17 upgrade?
update

Flutter version 3.0.0
This occured on android 12 (emulator) , checked with android 11(emulator) it is working as expected. is this related to OS?



It usually happens when you launch release version flutter app (and its widget system crashes). Can you launch it in debug mode with debugger attached (and check for debug logs)?

@StepanDyatkovskiy this is only with android 12 (in emulator). I've checked with android 11 emulator. is this anything related to the OS then ?

May be. But we need logs to figure out what happened. To do this, you should launch your app in debug mode and get debug logs.

i can see
[   +3 ms] Exception: Unsupported Android Plugin version: 7.4.2. when tried with flutter run -v
